# Nexus repository manager as pip local server not working properly

Tags: python, pip, nexus, localserver

A local nexus server has been setup as our pip local server.
I'm trying to install a sample/test class (inherits) using the said local server.
Uploading to the local server is successful, but installing using this command:

```
pip install -i http://<nexus-ip>:8081/repository/pypi-all/pypi inherits
```

Resulted to this:

```
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement inherits 
  (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for inherits
```

I also tried these commands, but the results are the same:

```
pip install inherits
pip install -i http://<nexus-ip>:8081/repository/pypi-all/pypi inherits-0.1
pip install -i http://<nexus-ip>:8081/repository/pypi-all/pypi inherits==0.1
```

Here're the contents of my ~/.pypirc:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    nexus
    pypi

[nexus]
username: my-username
password: mypassword
repository: http://<nexus-ip>:8081/nexus/repository/pypi-internal/

[pypi]
...
```

Here're the contents my ~/.config/pip/pip.conf

```
[global]
index = http://<nexus-ip>:8081/repository/pypi-all/pypi
index-url = http://<nexus-ip>:8081/repository/pypi-all/simple
```

As mentioned, uploading using below command is successful:

```
python setup.py sdist upload -r nexus
```

Response from the nexus server is here (i.e. signifies upload was successfull):

```
creating inherits-0.1
creating inherits-0.1/inherits
creating inherits-0.1/inherits.egg-info
copying files to inherits-0.1...
copying setup.cfg -> inherits-0.1
copying setup.py -> inherits-0.1
copying inherits/__init__.py -> inherits-0.1/inherits
copying inherits/addmult.py -> inherits-0.1/inherits
copying inherits/inherits.py -> inherits-0.1/inherits
copying inherits/subdiv.py -> inherits-0.1/inherits
copying inherits.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> inherits-0.1/inherits.egg-info
copying inherits.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> inherits-0.1/inherits.egg-info
copying inherits.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> inherits-0.1/inherits.egg-info
copying inherits.egg-info/top_level.txt -> inherits-0.1/inherits.egg-info
Writing inherits-0.1/setup.cfg
Creating tar archive
removing 'inherits-0.1' (and everything under it)
running upload
Submitting dist/inherits-0.1.tar.gz to http://<nexus-ip>:8081/nexus/repository/pypi-internal/
Server response (200): OK
```

Contents of the setup.py are the basic details:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import sys

try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

requires = []

setup( 
    name = "inherits",
    packages = ["inherits"],
    version = '0.1',
    description = 'Example inherits package',
    #url = "",
    #download_url = "",
    author = "Jayson Pryde",
    classifiers = [],
)
```

Any ideas on how to resolve this and make the pip install work? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try your `pip install` command with the `--verbose` flag for some more info?

Answer (score 15):

In case someone has encountered the same issue and is interested for a solution, here are two things I did.

**1. Execute pip using this:**

```
pip install inherits -i http://<nexus-ip>:8081/nexus/repository/pypi-all/simple -v --trusted-host <nexus-ip>
```

The -v and --trusted-host parameters are optional

**2. Move your ~/.config/pip/pip.conf to ~/.pip/pip.conf and execute:**

```
pip install inherits -v —trusted-host <nexus-ip>
```

Only challenge encountered with #2 is pip will always connect to the nexus server. So in case I want to connect to pypi.org, I have to rename the pip.conf first.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: which version of Nexus are you using, having the same issues

Comment: just to emphasize: it is critical to use `/simple` and not `/pypi` in option #1

Comment: @AlexFedulov's comment is actually the **key**

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem. I used the following steps to solve it. It works flawlessly now.

> In the following steps replace `pypi-mw` with your private nexus pypi registry name.

**Add Nexus user with all necessary privileges**

Create a new role. Filter all privileges by your pypi-registry name and add them all. Apply the new role to your user (you can fine-grain priveleges later):

[image]

**Edit .pypirc for upload credentials**

Put this into `~/.pypirc`

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi
    pypi-mw

[pypi]
repository: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username: peter

[pypi-mw]
repository: https://my-private-registry.com/repository/pypi-mw/
username: peter
```

**Edit pip.conf for download credentials**

Put this into `~/.pip/pip.conf`:

```
[global]
index = https://pypi.python.org/pypi/
index-url=https://pypi.python.org/simple/
extra-index-url=https://MY-NEXUS-USER:MY-NEXUS-PW@my-private-registry.com/repository/pypi-mw/simple/
trusted-host = my-private-registry.com
```

**Try it out**

If everything works like it should, you now have the option to upload your packages to `pypi` like this:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload
```

Or to your private registry:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel upload -r "pypi-mw"
```

To install a package you can run the usual command:

```
pip install mypackage --user
```

It should now search both registries (`pypi` and `pypi-mw`) for your package.

Answer (score 3):

Configuring pip with nexus repository in **Windows**

Create `pip.ini` in the folder `%APPDATA%/pip/pip.ini`, in your case go to your own `%APPDATA%` folder then create a text file `pip.ini` under `pip` folder

In my local m/c `%APPDATA%` is `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming>`

Add below lines in `pip.ini`

```
[global]
trusted-host=nexus.example.com:8443
index = https://nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/pypi
index-url = https://nexus.example.com/repository/pypi-group/simple
no-cache-dir = false
```

Then you can run the pip command from your windows command prompt

Answer (score 2):

I have encountered the same issue, and I resolved it by adding pypip-read and pypip-browse role to my anonymous user on Nexus.